# Digital RF signal vector resize algorithm

Tags: visualization, scaling

I'm searching for an algorithm for resizing a RF sampled signal in order to draw it without losing any important maximum or minimum values.

The values of the vector are negative/positive around zero.

[image: The signal in 1:1 scale]

[image: The signal in 2:1 scale]

Comment: I like Peter's answer, but I agree with him that this might not be what you want: Can you show a quick and dirty drawing of what you mean? Why is it important that it's an RF signal? "Drawing" implies you're using some software to do the drawing; what is that? Are you really asking us how to scale values with a factor, or how to set the boundaries of a drawing function?

Comment: It's important that it's RF signal because the meaning of the negative and positive values is crucial here. I need to scale down the drawing and still preserve the minimum and maximum values. I'm using my own drawing software to draw the signal. And yes, I simply need to scale the size of the sampled vector in such a way the the min/max values are still visible.

Comment: I'm using my own algorithm to calculate the values to draw. Obviously it's wrong. You can see that the scaled (lower) drawing is missing important peaks that are shown in the 1:1 scaled (upper) drawing.

Comment: Did you just decimate the signal to get the bottom figure from the top figure (i.e., did you just use every $n^{th}$ value)?

Comment: Due to the nature of your original drawing there are **lines** of **one** pixel width, whose **coarse** scaling is not possible from the plot. Instead, I suggest, you may consult to the original high-resoution RF data and **resample** it to fit into your new waveform display size. Now it shall preserve all the important peaks, as long as the original RF signal was oversampled enough.

Comment: No Matt L., what I did was finding the abs max from a group of points relative to their corresponding pixel and draw it. @Fat32, I'm afraid that is not an option for me. The current solution I came up with is drawing all points (not only abs max) and that creates a very dense signal drawing but at least this way I'm not losing the peaks. But I'm still looking for a more elegant solution for this matter.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not what you want, but using the [**convex hull**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of your points will preserve the minima and maxima.

[image: Convex hull of noise.]

---

**R Code Below**

```
#31780
T <- 1000
x <- rnorm(T,0,1)

ix <- seq(1,T)

ix_hpts <- chull(x = ix, y= x)

plot(ix_hpts, x[ix_hpts], type='l', col='red')
points(ix, x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just find the maximum and minimum value of your data; find the `absmax:= max(abs(min(data),max(data)))`. Scale your values by `factor:=height_of_window/2/absmax`.

The y-coordinate of your data point will by `y:= value * factor + height / 2` to keep the x=0 line centered in your drawing.

That's pretty basic (read: ninth grade) solving of linear equations...

Comment: Hi Marcus, either I didn't understand your answer or you didn't understand my Question. I'm not interesting in scaling the height, that is indeed basic calculations. I'm interested in scaling the width. for example, drawing X sampled points on to X/2 pixels.